# ModelBuilder not passing information through Iterate Feature Classes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, iteration, error-000728

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I am trying to create a model to iterate through three feature classes in a file geodatabase, all with the same schema. The model performs several joins and field calculations before eventually returning a feature class with several more fields in addition to the original fields. My problem is that the original fields aren't showing up in the model. For example, when specifying a join field, I get:

> Warning 000728: "Field ___ does not exist within the table"

As a result, they don't show up in the final feature class either.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a screenshot of the relevant part of the model:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your feature classes have aliases and/or fully qualified field names, ModelBuilder tools list aliases in field input drop downs, but check these against the field names e.g. offer "bacon test" as an option in a field input drop down, but check field names including "bacon_test".

Check the field name and type this into the join input rather than selecting from the drop down.

Comment: @Vince the field name is correct - the problem is that the only field options I get in the drop downs are from derived data (see Summarize Within tool), nothing from the original feature class. I've tried typing in the join field name that I want, but then I get the aforementioned warning.

Comment: My edit, but not my answer.